# De-activating the Core Voltage Regulator to Perform Power Analysis on STM32F407 DISCOVERY Board

Tags: aes, stm32, stm32f4discovery, power-analysis, side-channel-attacks

I am trying to perform Power Analysis (Side-Channel Attack) on AES-128 that I have implemented on STM32F407 DISCOVERY MCU. I have found out that I can measure with a current probe from VCap1 and Vcap2 . To do so, the regulator that feeds the core should be turned off and the processor should be fed with external power supply to minimize the noise. But the regulator is inside the core and I cannot take it off. How can I de-activate the regulator? Or is there any other way to perform Power Analysis on STM32F407VG MCU?

Comment: I've never heard that an attacker needs to do that. It requires privileges to do which means that one doesn't need to execute a power analysis at all.

Comment: Actually it is not necessarily done but with this way the possibility to find correlation with the key increases. I want to see a better correlation, so that I can find a prevention mechanism against Power Attack.

Answer (score 1):

I afraid it is not possible. The voltage regulator has to be `on` otherwise the core and peripherals clocks will not work. There is no way to switch this regulator `off`

You need to find another way.

Comment: Thank you for your precious comment :) I have to perform this analysis on STM32, so I will try to measure without turning off the regulator.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet mentions that, on some packages, there is pin called `BYPASS_REG` which can be used to disable internal voltage regulator and allow you to supply core using V_CAP pins. See *Section 2.2.16 Voltage Regulator* in the STM32F407 datasheet (DS8626).

Unfortunately, STM32F407V present on Discovery Board isn't one of the packages which feature `BYPASS_REG` pin. This pin is present on WLCSP90, UFBGA176 and LQFP176 packages, according to *Table 3. Regulator ON/OFF and internal reset ON/OFF availability*.

Comment: First of all thank you for your detailed research and comment. Like you have mentioned, Bypass_reg seems like not available on STM32F407VG Discovery board. Therefore the signal will be noisy anyway.